# .htaccess conditions: https, www, rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

**Would like to do the following on my website using .htaccess rewrite mod:**

- redirect users without https://* to https://*
- redirect users with *www.example.com* to *example.com*
- rewrite *example.com/index.htm* to *example.com/home*
- redirect every URI to *index.htm* exept of */home*, */background.jpg*, */icon.png* and */fonts/segoeui.ttf*

---

**This is the code I already have:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

# --- Part that looks stupid but is working ---
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# --- Part that is not really working ---
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.htm)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.htm [L,R=301]
```

So, is there a better way to combine the *https* and the *www* thing? It is more a copy and paste solution than good code. I have not much knowledge with this.

The redirection to *index.htm* is working, but how can I prevent */background.jpg*, */icon.png* and */fonts/segoeui.ttf* from being redirected too? And what about rewriting the whole thing to */home*?

---

**Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine first two conditions in only one

```
# Force https and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then, *rewrite example.com/index.htm to example.com/home*

```
# Redirect /index.htm to /home and avoids infinite redirect loop
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.htm\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home [R=301,L]

# Rewrite (internally) /home to /index.htm
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.htm [L]
```

Finally, *redirect every URI to index.htm exept of /home, /background.jpg, /icon.png and /fonts/segoeui.ttf*

```
# Redirect (if not an existing file) to /index.htm (which will after redirect to /home)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Thanks for your help!